# CI/CD to angular web app in azure devops succeeded but nothing happen

Tags: angular, azure, web-applications, azure-devops, devops

I try to deploy an angular web app to azure and in order to do this I use azure devops, after a lot of Attempts I managed to build  ci/cd pipeline that work but the problem is that when I go to the url where the app was supposed to run, nothing is updated and I see the default page.
the following is the yml that I used:

[image: yml file]
in addition this is the stages of the build:
[image: The stages of the build]

and this is the the stages of the release:
[image: release stages]

[image: log of deploy to azure]

in addintion i uplod the log file to my github account- https://github.com/galoren287199/LogToProject
I'll very appreciate any help here ,
best regards ,
gal :)

Comment: Can you show us log of `Deploy Azure App Service` step from release pipeline?

Comment: hello @KrzysztofMadej i edit the publish and add a picture of the Deploy Azure App Service step and link to logfile in my github account I'll appreciate if you take a look :)

Comment: Based on log all looks fine. Can you show us what you have in `wwwroot` on Azure using Kudu Console for instance.

Comment: Am I right that your App Plan is Linux based? If yes, can you check this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532386/hosting-angular-application-in-azure-linux-app-service

Comment: hello @Cece Dong - MSFT  I get complicated with the inputs for the task ,very appricate if you can help with it ,in addition I append link  to my github repositry that consist  the logfile in the post ,

Comment: @גלאורן How's your issue going?

Comment: hello ,I succeeded  to solve my problem ,i recompose the pipe again manually but in addition i found two problems that i had to fix .
first i read that  because the machine that i run on its linux its not open automatically a web server like iis in windows so i found the following issue useful for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59707804/deployed-angular-app-to-azure-web-app-but-showing-the-default-azure-page
furthermore the root folder that i reference  in the beginning was build.sourcedirectory i change it the place where the build was created it is dist\"the name of my app" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded to solve my problem ,i recompose the pipe again manually but in addition i found two problems that i had to fix . first i read that because the machine that i run on its linux its not open automatically a web server like iis in windows so i found the following issue useful for it stackoverflow.com/questions/59707804/… furthermore the root folder that i reference in the beginning was build.sourcedirectory i change it the place where the build was created it is dist"the name of my app" :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try `AzureRMWebAppDeployment@4` task directly after `ArchiveFiles` task. In this way, you don't need a release stage. If you still can't get it work, share the detailed log.

[image]

```
      - task: AzureRMWebAppDeployment@4
```